# Correct use of subjunctive

Tags: subjunctive-mood

I am really curious about one thing;that is the use of the past simple when normally,a subjunctive should be used.
For instance,here:
"It is vital that he should go to school" or "It is vital that he go to school".
I was wondering whether "It is vital that he went to school" is gramatically correct.
Some of my teachers say it is,some deny it.

Thanks

Comment: It sounds odd to me. I suspect it arises from a confusion with the "past subjunctive", which is used in counterfactual conditionals, and is identical with the simple past for every word in the language other than "were".

Comment: It sounds odd to me, too. So while AmE and BrE often differ in uses of the subjunctive, they don't here.

Comment: Ok,thanks.But the other two variants that use the subjunctive are correct right?

Comment: No, it’s not grammatical. You can use the past 'tense' in something like _If he went to school tomorrow …_ where that use of past “went” has nothing to with time but with modality and hence is called a modal preterite. Your other examples are fine, they're both mandatives, but only the second one is a subjunctive mandative. The first one is sometimes called a 'should mandative'

Comment: Doesn't it need to be *It WAS vital that he went to school*. As @Colin Fine says the past subjunctive is the same as the past indicative for every verb in the language except *were*.  *It was vital that he were properly prepared*.

Comment: @WS2: in the U.S., the proper use of the subjunctive would be *"It was vital that he **go** to school."*

Comment: @PeterShor I think most of the time it would be in Britain too. It was just that the OP posted *It is vital that he went to school*, as a suggestion. And if you were to use *went* (not necessarily recommended) it would be necessary to switch *is* to *was*. But *It was necessary that he go to school* sounds the better way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't speak for the Brits, but here are my thoughts on American English:
"It is vital that he should go to school" and "It is vital that he go to school" are semantically equivalent, and both are grammatically correct. (Just spare us the abomination "It is vital that he goes to school", where "goes" is intended to function as a subjunctive. This is similar to the example provided by jimm101.)

"It is vital that he went to school" is grammatically and semantically correct IN THE SENSE explained by jimm101. However, as noted by colin, that interpretation changes the meaning of "vital", and "went" is no longer a subjunctive.

Therefore, either of your teachers might be correct, DEPENDING on the context and the intended interpretation of the sentence.

(As an aside, the example "It was vital that he were properly prepared", given by WS2, I find both ungrammatical and nonsensical. What does this sentence mean? Is that a British construct?)

Answer (score 1):

"It is vital that he went to school" can be valid in a particular context. For instance, you may be analyzing the behavior of a historical figure, and make a similar statement, such as:

> John could not have murdered Mary, because he went to school that day. His teachers saw him, the other students saw him, and he wasn't marked as absent. Some will argue that it doesn't matter whether he went to school, because he had a motive and he had threatend. But this isn't true. **It is vital the he went to school.** It's the cornerstone of his defense.

Comment: True. But that is a very different meaning of "it is vital" - it means that the fact is important (for an argument), as opposed to it being necessary. An epistemic reading as opposed to the usual deontic one.

Comment: This is not the subjunctive. This is the indicative. In your example you're saying he actually went to school. Not that he should have.